# Add textView to relativeLayout which is inside scrollView Dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

I have  `RelativeLayout` inside `ScrollView`.. and I am trying to add `TextView` 'tv' below `textView22` ...
item : is an object.

When I run the program, I don't see the new textView though there are NO errors in my code.

Any suggestions?

```
RelativeLayout s = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RL) ;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,   
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);    

TextView tv = new TextView(Post.this);                                  
tv.setText(item.getString("comment"));
p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW , R.id.textView22 );
tv.setTextSize(18) ;
tv.setTextColor( 0xaaaaff );
s.addView(tv , p );
```

EDIT 2

You can see there is a value of this textView (in the left, look at 'mtext' in the table) but I don't see it in screen!

[image]

Comment: What is your actual question/problem?

Comment: When I run the program, I don't see the new textView though there is NO errors in my code

Comment: you might try the hiearchyviewer - it can examine a snapshot of your UI (after you add the new textview) and you can look eat each view's parameters.  Maybe it's simply off screen?

Comment: Have you checked that item.getString("comment") is having any Value?

Comment: Via hiearchyviewer  I see there is a value!